# Making viapoints draggable in Bing Maps v8

Tags: bing-maps

I've seen a lot of posts that say v8 does not yet support viapointPushpinOptions and I was wondering if that was still the case. What I would like to do is make viapoints draggable, but have not yet figured out how. This is the code I have...

```
directionsManager.setRenderOptions({  
    viapointPushpinOptions: { visible: false },
    viapointPushpinOptions: { draggable: true }
});
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The viapointPushpinOptions property is deprecated and there are no plans to add it to V8. In V8 you can use the following for waypoint customizations:

```
waypointPushpinOptions
firstWaypointPushpinOptions
lastWaypointPushpinOptions
```

That said, we are planning to add a function soon to the directions manager to get all pushpins for the route which would make it easy to go through and customize each one as much as you want. That should be in the experimental branch soon if it isn't already there and will likely be in the main release branch in a few weeks.

If you can't wait, you can always hide all waypoints, then loop through the route data and create custom pushpins for each waypoint as you see fit. Here is a sample: http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#Fully%20Custom%20Waypoint%20Pushpins

Comment: When I drag the route a via waypoint is created at the new location. Are these via waypoints included in the route data? I tried to implement the example you provided and still wasn't able to customize these via waypoints.

Comment: Not currently, but will be available soon using the getallWaypoints function of the directions manager.